# Implementing Facebook Login with conditional redirection in iOS SDK

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook, info.plist

I have a requirement to integrate facebook login in my iOS app, everything is fine according to the instructions given at the below link
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/getting-started

However I have a scenario where I need to implement a conditional redirection for facebook, such as

```
  if (User is Not Logged In)
{

Then redirect to The Installed Facebook application and Get the details of user from the Facebook Application

 }
else
{
 // If user is logged in 
  Then Open a Webview to Enter Login
 Credentials
}
```

my problem is due to placing the URL Schemes under URL types in info.plist I can open it in only one manner across the application,

Either I place The facebookId `URL schema` as the First Object and open the Installed facebook app, or Place it as second Object to open a Webview

Is there any way possible where I can check if the user is logged in then place the URL Schema at the top and not make it fallback to webview, but if not I  Change it to be the first object in URL Types so it open the installed Facebook Application for Login

Comment: If you use the LoginButton, it will handle all of that for you.